# Are these the correct nouns? "... responsibilities consisted of ensuring continuity of reception and in-house mail services."

Tags: nouns

"... responsibilities consisted of ensuring continuity of reception and in-house mail services."

1. Is it "continuity" or "continuation"?
2. Is it "reception service" or "receptionist service"?

Comment: Context: The organization consists of union employees and exempt employees. In the event of a strike, the union employees will not be present. However, business must go on as usual, and exempt employees will be re-assigned to fulfill the duties and responsibilities of those union roles. Therefore, the exempt employees are also responsible for ensuring that the phones are answered and mail is delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is "continuity" because you don't want service to be interrupted.   However "of" is awkward, so replace it with "continuous."  Also, receptionist is the person who answers the phone.  Reception is the area or desk where visitors and guest are welcomed.  There could also be a receptionist at reception.  I would write: "...responsibilities consisted of ensuring continuous reception and in-house mail services."

Answer (score 0):

The word I believe you should use is "continuation" because the position requires the job to "continue." The word "continuity" is generally used in context of the existing flow of something. So to use it would be "maintain the continuity of..."